# Доступ к реестру без "Запустить от имени администратора"

Tags: c#, реестр

Сначала этот кусок кода (добавление программы в автозапуск) не работал

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey Key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\", true);
 Key.SetValue("Krekker", "Programma.exe");
```

Решением было запустить программы от имени администратора. Но как сделать это без запуска от администратора? Возможно ли такое?

Comment: Писать в юзер_шкей, а не в локал_машину_шкей. Так-же можно вызывать отдельный Шелл с параметром `runas`, но спрашивать все равно будет.

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, в виде ответа. Буду рад, если будет прикреплен пример.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В последних линейках **Windows** доступ к разделу `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` ради безопасности организован через привилегии администратора, процесс должен быть запущен с флагом `runas`.

Но, можно как и прежде пользоваться разделом `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` с обычными правами.

**64-битная Windows**

Так-же, если писать в ветку `SOFTWARE` не с правами администратора, виртуализация реестра перенаправляет запись в ветку `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` (зависит от настроек на ПК).

И на последок есть две утилиты regedit.
`?:\Windows?\System32\regedt32.exe` и `?:\Windows?\SysWOW64\regedt32.exe`. Каждая из них дает вам различные Registry.

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/WinProg64/registry-redirector

Примерчик для `C#`

```
Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey (@"MyKey", true);
```

Comment: Дописал примерчик

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE всегда был доступен только админу во всей линейке Win NT. В остальном +

Comment: Но не во всей линейке было диалоговое окно запуска в админ режиме, достаточно было зайти пользователем с правами администратора.

Comment: Ну защита от админа-дурака, да, появилась только в висте. Но это не отменяет утверждения, что во всей линейке требовались привилегии администратора.